# Javascript: From a given array, get a reduced array of the elements that a string contains

Tags: javascript

From these random **string** and **array**:

```
var str = "She folded her handkerchief neatly.";
var arr = ['foo', 'folded', 'bar', 'neatly'];
```

How to get a **reduced array** which only keeps the **values** contained in the **string** ?

```
var res = ['folded', 'neatly'];
```

Comment: split, filter, includes

Comment: Can you show us your current attempt?

Comment: Split the string into array and then you can looping the new formed array compare with your second array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an easy task to do with [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```js
var str = "She folded her handkerchief neatly.";
var arr = ['foo', 'folded', 'bar', 'neatly'];

let res = arr.filter(s => str.match(s));
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: @maxagaz: Keep in mind that this will match any part of a word in the string, so if `"eat"` was in the array, it would count as a match.

Comment: @zi Good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `Array.filter` and `String.includes`

```
var str = "She folded her handkerchief neatly.";
var arr = ['foo', 'folded', 'bar', 'neatly'];

filteredArr = arr.filter(item => str.includes(item))

console.log(filteredArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

By using new JS features. You can use **ES6** `includes()` function. 
And it works faster than other methods in terms of *performance*

```
var str = "She folded her handkerchief neatly.";
var arr = ['foo', 'folded', 'bar', 'neatly'];

let res = [];
arr.forEach((arrString) => {
  str.includes(arrString) ? 
    res.push(arrString)   :
    return;
});
console.log(res);
```